# Django model Field default=None useful?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my current project I'm working on we use `default=None` on model Fields, for `models.CharField(default='')`. Does this make any sense? I looked into the Django documentation, but couldn't find an answer. I searched the Django source code and for models Field the initial is set to `default=NOT_PROVIDED` and this is defined as

```py
class NOT_PROVIDED:
    pass
```

so I'm even more confused now. Running my tests in the Django project I had the feeling, that it does not really matter if I used `default=None` or `default=''`

Comment: default=None is the same as not using default parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the difference depends on the use you are going to make of that specific data. For most cases, there is no difference, but you must have clear that `''` and `None` are different Python data types:

```
>>> type('')
<class 'str'>
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

So there would be a difference when the data type is transcendent in the use context of the data.

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
> TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has
> two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most
> cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the
> Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception
> is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this
> situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations
> when saving multiple objects with blank values.